# Different Behaviour of endl and \n with fork()

Tags: c++, fork

I have a c++ program which creates five child processes.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        cout<<"Child Process 1"<<endl;
    }

    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        cout<<"Child Process 2"<<endl;
    }

     if(pid==0)
    {
        pid=fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
            cout<<"child process 3"<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
Child Process 1
Child Process 2
Child Process 2
child process 3
child process 3
```

But the problem is when i use \n instead of endl the output is different

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        cout<<"Child Process 1\n";
    }

    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        cout<<"Child Process 2\n";
    }

     if(pid==0)
    {
        pid=fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
            cout<<"child process 3\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of above program using \n is:

```
Child Process 1
Child Process 2
Child Process 1
Child Process 2
Child Process 2
child process 3
Child Process 1
Child Process 2
child process 3
```

why is the output different for endl and \n in the same program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::cout` normally does not print text immediately but keeps it in a buffer. When the process is forked, that internal buffer is copied along with everything else in the process; parent and child end up with identical buffers.

What apparently happens in your example is that the buffer is only flushed and printed to the screen after the fork, probably just before the process ends.

With `std::endl`, then the buffer is flushed *immediately* as a side effect, so the contents are printed by the parent process before the child process can get a copy.

Comment: Yup, this is the better answer of the two. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Most operating systems *buffer* the standard output as an optimisation.

`endl` as well as writing a newline character, also *flushes* the buffer which essentially means that any queued standard output is written to the console immediately.

`\n` does not flush the buffer.

So your difference in output is due to this interacting with your concurrency model.

Comment: Your final line, while correct, is rather opaque. Better to talk about how the unflushed buffer is copied into the new process, then everything is clear. Christian wrote an excellent answer but deleted it right away :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thank you both. I just deleted it because the answer suddenly felt somewhat incomplete and unverified to me the very moment I pressed the send button, and I didn't have to polish and review it. If you think it's good I'll leave it undeleted, of course.